# Firefox, Charis SIL and Serbian cursive

Tags: firefox, fonts, cyrillic

Let's view the following example in Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Charis SIL 5.000 installed:

```html
<html lang="sr">
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body style="font-family: 'Charis SIL'; font-style: italic">
кућа ми је отворена, моја ватра угашена<br>
зато, ако желиш, боже кише, само напред, пошаљи пљусак
</body>
</html>
```

It displays Russian versions of т, г, б and п instead of Serbian versions.
If I remove the `font-family` property or change it to some other value, like `'Ubuntu'` or `'Noto Serif'` or `'Caladea'`, Serbian versions are displayed correctly. If I view the same snippet unchanged in Chrome or Opera, they also display Serbian versions correctly. However, the combination of Firefox and Charis SIL somehow doesn't work. Why?

[Here](https://zabolekar.github.io/) is a similar example using .woff so you don't have to install the font.

Here is a screenshot of how it should be (with Serbian cursive, taken in Chrome):

[image: 3]

And here is what it looks like in Firefox (with Russian cursive):

[image: 2]

Comment: I'm not installing a font just to test your code, so feel free to create a web example using a .woff source for `@font-face` use, but in the mean time: what happens if write normal HTML, with a `<p lang="sr">кућа ми је отворена, моја ватра угашена зато, ако желиш, боже кише, само напред, пошаљи пљусак</p>` instead of dropping text in the body tag without any markup?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no visible changes

Comment: Can you put up an example for this on a test gh-pages or something?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans just did it and edited the post

Comment: thank you - can you also include what it's supposed to look like, though? Many of the people here won't know anything about Serbian, even if they know a lot about opentype and html5/css3

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans done!

Comment: Hm, the only thing I can conclude here is that this is a bug in firefox - you probably want to hit up bugzilla.mozilla.org and file a bug around this.

Comment: Not an expert either, but it seems indeed related to the `lang` attribute. When removed in chrome, we get the same result as in FF.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok, submitted it at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1479337, let's see what they say.